# XmlReader failed to read all the nodes

Tags: c#, xml

I am writing a custom XML parsing for one of my needs. The intent of the program is to parse any kind of XML file which matches the Main node.
I have replicated the problem as below.
The main intent of ReadXml(), ParseData() methods to read the data of XML element if a match found otherwise it should advance to the next Node.
But the input XML has one extra Node 'title1' , because of this node the parsing program broke without reading the 'author' Node.

```
   class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

        String xmlString =
            @"<bookstore>
                    <book genre='autobiography' publicationdate='1981-03-22' ISBN='1-861003-11-0'>
                        <title>The Autobiography of Benjamin Franklin</title> 
                       <title1>The Autobiography of Benjamin Franklin</title1>                           
                        <author>                           
                            <first-name>Benjamin</first-name>
                            <last-name>Franklin</last-name>                          
                        </author>
                        <author2>
                            <first-name>Benjamin</first-name>
                            <last-name>Franklin</last-name>
                        </author2>
                        <price>8.99</price>
                    </book>
               </bookstore>";

        // Create an XmlReader
        using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xmlString)))
        {
            ReadXml(reader);
        }
    }



    public static void ReadXml(System.Xml.XmlReader reader)
    {
        if (reader.MoveToContent() == XmlNodeType.Element &&
            reader.LocalName == "bookstore")
        {
            reader.Read();
            // Parse the file and display each of the nodes.
            do
            {
                switch (reader.NodeType)
                {
                    case XmlNodeType.Element:
                        ParseData(reader);
                        break;
                    case XmlNodeType.Text:
                    case XmlNodeType.CDATA:
                    case XmlNodeType.ProcessingInstruction:
                    case XmlNodeType.Comment:
                    case XmlNodeType.XmlDeclaration:
                    case XmlNodeType.Document:
                    case XmlNodeType.EntityReference:
                    case XmlNodeType.EndElement:
                        break;
                }

                if (reader.ReadState == ReadState.Interactive)
                    reader.Read();

            } while (!reader.EOF && reader.NodeType != XmlNodeType.EndElement);

        }
    }


    protected static bool ParseData(System.Xml.XmlReader reader)
    {
        string output = string.Empty;
        bool parsed = true;
        switch (reader.LocalName)
        {
            case "title":
                output = reader.ReadString();
                break;               
            case "author":
                XmlReader reagentListReader = reader.ReadSubtree();     // This case never reached              
                break;             
            default:
               // output = reader.ReadString(); //uncomment will work,But                             //not sure to read subtree or string.
                parsed = false;
                break;
        }
        return parsed;
    }
}
```

By adding ' output = reader.ReadString();' in default : switch case solves my problem but i never know it is to read Subtree or a String.

Comment: Is there a reason you're parsing this way? Is the 'real' file extremely large?

Comment: Yes, The real file is larger and can grow to any size. The real file can be updated by different user and send to customer. The software should handle the new XML at any specific scenario.

Comment: When you want to ignore certain tags then you _should_ read the entire subtree.

Comment: Also, add WhiteSpace to your ignore list.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your loop condition - you're exiting as when it reaches an `EndElement`.  You can verify this if you step through it - it will be reached for those elements you're ignoring as `reader.Read` is called.

Just change the condition to:

```
while (!reader.EOF);
```

Comment: This is working, but the size of the file and performance of the program is a concern.

Comment: Can you explain why reader.Read() is not moving to the next node instead   iterating text, endelement..

Comment: That's how it works, it reads all the parts in order, e.g. element, attributes, content (may include more elements), then end element.